# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id while inserting user records

Tags: apex, salesforce2salesforce

I am adding users from developer console. when I will insert one by one in loop, records are inserting but when I am adding it in list and then inserting list in salesforce using DML query its giving below exception:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, UserTrigger: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 0039000000lLxNgAAK; first error:
>   INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call:
>   [Id] Trigger.UserTrigger: line 31, column 1: []: AnonymousBlock: line
>   11, column 1

Here is my code

```
list<User> use = new list<User>();
Profile proID = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'Chatter Free User'];
for(integer i=1;i<5;i++){
    user u2 = new user(LastName = 'ITHD User' + i, 
                       Email = 'madhura.gadewar@gmail.com', 
                       UserName = 'ithduser' + i + '@gmail.com', 
                       CommunityNickname = 'madhura.gadewar' + i,Alias='tithd'+i,
                       ProfileID = proID.ID,
                       EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                       LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                       LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                       TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago');
    use.add(u2); 
}
insert use;
```

Comment: Can you show us your UserTrigger?

Comment: The error is being reported in the `UserTrigger`, it would help if we could see that code.

Comment: I see a lot of downvoting on this question and its answers: it helps to leave a comment explaining why, so the people asking/answering can improve the quality of the question and answers.

Comment: I'm guessing all the downvoting is because he didn't give the code that the error specifically mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Error is not due this code that you are executing . There two parts in the error :

1) It is erroring out at UserTrigger (as pointed out by rest )
2) It is erroring on Contact record , look at the id it starts with "003"

Unless you debug the trigger that is erroring outwe wudnt know what is happening.

Answer (score -2):

try the following code.  The problem happens when click execute button second time as users with same user name executes.  Try to use current time in millies as part of username

```
list<User> use = new list<User>();
 user u2;
Profile proID = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'Chatter Free User'];


for(integer i=1;i<5;i++){
     System.debug(i);
    Datetime  dt = system.now();
   u2 = new user();
        u2.LastName =  'ITHD User' + i;
        u2.Email = 'madhura.gadewar@gmail.com';
        u2.UserName = 'ithduser' +  dt.getTime() + '@gmail.com';
    u2.CommunityNickname = 'madhura.gadewar' + i;
    u2.Alias='tithd'+i;
    u2.ProfileID = proID.ID;
    u2.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u2.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u2.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u2.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago';
    use.add(u2); 
}
insert use;
```

Answer (score -3):

Problem is, your code is small enough / quick enough that it's getting the same dateTime stamp. You'll need to use something more than just the millisecond timestamp to differentiate your users. Try generating a UUID, or salting your timestamp with a random number (random # isn't 100% sure to work)